# Adding placeholder text field to woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, pluggable

I am trying to add placeholder text to checkout page but it is not displaying any placeholder text on the first name and last name.It is displaying a new text field with the palceholder text which i have written.I just want to add the placegolder text in the existing field instead of adding a new text field.Written the code in themes/function.php file but still it is not working.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_default_address_checkout_fields', 20, 1);
function override_default_address_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
$address_fields['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Enter your first name';
$address_fields['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Enter your last name';
return $address_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code in your themes `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );

function override_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Enter First Name';
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Enter Last Name';
    return $fields;
}
```

Solved by adding the code in this way